# R - How to plot a clmm2 model with sjPlot package

Tags: r, sjplot

I have been able to make several beautiful plots with the `plot_model` function of the `sjPlot` package. However, I have not found a successful means by which to input a `clmm2` model (from the `ordinal` package). Is there any known support or suggested alternative for plotting a `clmm2` models's 2-way interaction via `sjPlot`?

Comment: afaik, neither packages _ggeffects_ (which is used by sjPlot for marginal effects plots), nor _effects_ or _emmeans_ work with clmm2-models. I'm not aware of any alternative packages.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the closest solutions I could find were the plot approaches suggested at https://data.library.virginia.edu/visualizing-the-effects-of-proportional-odds-logistic-regression/ and https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-perform-ordinal-logistic-regression-in-r/